# AJAX .load() returns NULL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, asynchronous

I'm building a website in PHP and I'm trying to implement asynchonous behaviour on some occasions, in this case to load an HTML form into an overlay and making it visible. This works as intended, however I'm now testing everything considering existing data.

So I basically created a `variables.php` file that sets values to the `$_SESSION` global and was working from there. Everything was working as expected on `index.php`, but as soon as I click the overlay I notice the values aren't passing through to populate the form that was added.

I already poked google for a few hours to no avail. I've added `echo var_dump($_SESSION);` on the `index.php` file and the values are all there. However on the overlay it returns NULL. I've even `include_once("loginForm.php")` right in the middle of index.php and that gave me the values. So there's something I'm missing in order to get the values to apply to `.load()` elements.

Here's some code:

variables.php

```
//added values to the $_SESSION global for testing purposes 
$_SESSION['email'] = 'john@john.com';
$_SESSION['password'] = 'johnny';
$_SESSION['name'] = 'John';
$_SESSION['surname'] = 'Smith';
$_SESSION['country'] = 'UK';
$_SESSION['phoneOption'] = 'Mobile';
$_SESSION['phone'] = '987654321';
```

header-login.php

```
//this form accepts an email to check ifExists() and decide what's next
//the input #preLoginEmail assumes the value correctly
<form action="header-login.php" name="preLoginForm" id="preLoginForm" method="post">
<div id="login-part2">
    <table id="preLoginTable">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" id="preLoginEmail" title="Email" name="test-email" tabindex="1" size="10" maxlength="60" placeholder="Email" value="'. $email .'" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a title="forgotten password" href="header-login.php" id="preLoginForgot">forgot password?</a></td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn1" name="preLoginRegisterButton" id="preLoginRegisterButton" tabindex="1" value="Login / Register" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    echo var_dump($_SESSION);//works
</form>
```

onClickEvents.js

```
//this call retrieves the HTML correctly although the variables dont get assigned to the input's value
$( "#preLoginForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
var $form = $( this ),
term = $form.find( "input[name='test-email']" ).val(),
url = $form.attr( "action" );
verifiedEmail = validateEmail(term);

if(verifiedEmail){
    // Put the results in a div
    $('#olContainer').load("../inc/loginForm.php");
    overlayOn();
}
else {
    $('.session-stat').css({ "background-color": "#A60000" });
}
});
```

loginForm.php

```
//when this form is loaded there are no values in the inputs and var_dump($_SESSION) returns NULL
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="booking.php">
    //some blocks are static and created in plain html
    <input name="email" type="text" class="dDown12" id="agentuser" size="20" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    //others are php variables to make the if/else statement more readable
    $countryBlock ='<input name="agentuser" type="text" class="dDown12" id="agentuser" size="20" maxlength="20" value="'. $country .'" />';
    echo var_dump($_SESSION); //NULL
```

I kinda ran out of ways to figure out what's going wrong, and I just started learning about AJAX this week. If u need anything else just let me know in comments I'll try to be quick to edit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you including session_start(); in the top of those files? Unless you do, a session won't write. Also you must call session_start() before any other output is made - HTML or PHP.

Comment: Even in the partial file where i just grab the HTML from?

Comment: Yes, especially there, or else it won't have access to the session you've created.  Be careful also with sessions and ajax - session race conditions will and do occur.

Comment: Just added the `session_start();` it works now... I feel so dumb right now... i was warned about this and totally forgot. Btw what do you mean with session race conditions?

Comment: I was looking deeper at your form, I'm glad it's working now, but in the past when I've had to use ajax to .load(), you can pass all the form data in the .load(url, data, function(){...  the data variable can be created by using jquery's serialize, as in yours would be: data = $form.serialize(); This will automatically post the form values to the ajax form, so there will be no need to mess around with sessions. simply access it through $_POST['test-email'] in loginForm.php.  As to Session Race conditions, search for ajax session race conditions here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I was thinking about using AJAX to "summon" bits and pieces of HTML on the fly and css changes with easier/less coding to it. User input validation as well and I might do an occasional DB query to verify the user or populate an array. Other then that, form submissions would carry out the submit. I'm a novice programmer... I wouldn't want to get in over my head, but I was trying to implement AJAX as a learning experience. But from what I've glanced at the session race conditions, that seems to be quite complex.

Comment: Would you still advise me to move away from sessions? If that's the case I believe I'd have to move away from AJAX, since I can pull this off synchronously with javascript validation and a page reload at the end of each form.

Comment: Don't be daunted by session race, just look out for it when you are doing many ajax calls at once and perhaps querying a database where the last action a user does may not be what is returned (may have been an earlier action). As for form validation, I think it's a good way, but you can still use Ajax and post the data even if fields are empty, you can still check the ones that are populated. and send back an error response if needed. Good luck!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44025/discussion-between-fernando-silva-and-chas688)

Comment: @chas688 don't forget to post an answer so i can accept it^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fernando - I didn't know which way you decided to go, but if you have to use $_SESSION for this, include:

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of each file you plan to use sessions on, before any content is rendered. Also, be careful to have a means for your users to overwrite their values, ie. with a post, so that once a value gets put in session, there is a way to change it and it doesn't keep overwriting the (new) value.  I usually clear out my sessions on Page one of the form. You can do a

```
unset($_SESSION['test-email']);
```

...to unset the values. You can use a foreach loop here too.

A great site to compare the speed of loops in PHP is http://www.phpbench.com/ also.
Best of luck!